# Migrating or exporting a database from azure to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am playing around with SQL Azure and in my learning curve. I Have migrated a database from my on premises instance to the Azure server. Now my question is, how do I move a database from Azure to on premises instance.

**Source** : Azure , Database name : Azuretest

**Destination** : Sql server 2016 on premises instance in my laptop.

Is Azure to On Premise database migration possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Export the Data-tier to local disk from the Azure database. It will save a bacpac file.
>
> Right click the database you need to export --> Task-->Export
>   data-tier application and follow the steps until the bacpac file is
>   created.
>
> 2. Import the backpack file from the local disk to the On premises Instance by using the same utility from tasks.
>
> Right click the database branch in your on premise instance --> Import
>   data tier application and now use the bacpac file saved in first step
>   to create the database.

[image]

Comment: That will only do data, how about schema?

Comment: It will do the whole database.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application

Comment: Thank you. I hit extract instead of export and only saw option for dacpac and not bacpac. Sorry about that.

Comment: No harm done. :)

Comment: @DanielBjörk : |Works like a charm.

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi great to hear.. Good luck in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs more details on the steps as mentioned by Daniel:

> 1. Export the Data-tier to local disk from the Azure database. It will save a bacpac file.
>
> Right click the database you need to export --> Task-->Export
>   data-tier application and follow the steps until the bacpac file is
>   created.
>
> 2. Import the backpack file from the local disk to the On premises Instance by using the same utility from tasks.
>
> Right click the database branch in your on premise instance --> Import
>   data tier application and now use the bacpac file saved in first step
>   to create the database.

Thank you Daniel.

[image]

Comment: I updated the answer with your more detailed description.

Comment: Awesome! I am sure this will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating an empty database in Azure.**

```
USE [master] 
GO

CREATE DATABASE [Migrate2OnPrem] 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Migrate2OnPrem] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130 
GO


ALTER DATABASE [Migrate2OnPrem] SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE, 
CLEANUP_POLICY = (STALE_QUERY_THRESHOLD_DAYS = 7), DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 900, 
INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES = 60, MAX_STORAGE_SIZE_MB = 10, QUERY_CAPTURE_MODE = AUTO, 
SIZE_BASED_CLEANUP_MODE = AUTO) 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Migrate2OnPrem] SET  READ_WRITE  GO
```

**Exporting database to a .bacpac file**

Using [sqlpackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) action `Export` create a `.bacpac` file at my local host.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\"


.\SqlPackage.exe /Action:Export /SourceServerName:tcp:taiobadw.database.windows.net,1433  
 /SourceDatabaseName:Migrate2OnPrem /su:taiobmdjamshed /sp:password 
 /TargetFile:"C:\Migrate2OnPrem.bacpac"
```

**Importing to On-Prem server**

Using [sqlpackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) action `Import` import the  `.bacpac` file from my local host (that you created in the step above.

```
.\sqlpackage.exe /a:Import /sf:C:\Migrate2OnPrem.bacpac /tsn:localhost /tdn:Migrate2OnPrem
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides export\import .bacpac described by other users, there is another way to migrate a database, which in many cases may be preferable.

You can create a .sql script of Azure database and then run it in SQL Server

**Generate t-sql script via Sql Server Managment Studio**

right click on database -> Generate script

[image]

The Script Wizard will open.

In the *Set Scripting Options* section, click the *Advanced*. Specify the *Types of data for script* option to *Schema and Data*. Pay attention to the options *Script for server version* and *Script for database engine type*, here you can choose which database to create the script for.

[image]

Specify where the script should be saved and click Finish

To import a .sql file, simply open it in Sql Server Managment Studio and press F5. If the .sql file is very large then you can use the sqlcmd utility.

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\<your file here>.sql
```

Note, when creating a .sql script or Export data tier application, **the data should not be changed in the database**, since these methods do not provide transactional consistency of the exported data. If you are exporting a live database, then create a copy of it temporarily for export.

```
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorksCopy
AS COPY OF AdventureWorks
GO
```