# Backup from dacpac file extracted using SSDT

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssdt, azure-sql-managed-instance

I tried method given in this answer by Ramankant Dadhichi but deploying failed:

[Backup a database from Azure SQL Managed Instance and restore to on premise SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244167/backup-a-database-from-azure-sql-managed-instance-and-restore-to-on-premise-sql?newreg=ec931412355c4730acfff21d2c7c78cd)

I have my database in Azure SQL Managed Instance. I extracted a dacpac using SSDT. But, now when I try to deploy the extracted file using SSMS, I get the following error:

> Could not deploy package.
> Error SQL0: The element [releaseengineer] cannot be deployed. This element contains state that cannot be recreated in the target database.
> Error SQL0: The element [Reporter] cannot be deployed. This element contains state that cannot be recreated in the target database.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Comment: In your database, what object types are "realeaseengineer" and "Reporter"?

Comment: they are users, owner of some schemas

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the commentary [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/118c5330-6941-445c-9b51-c51cc08ef858/script-generation-error-in-schema-compare-after-upgrading-to-ssdt-111407060-in-vs2012?forum=ssdt). Has the login been created on each instance using the same SID?  If not then this might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: I have deleted those users and that error got solved but now its showing error that certificate and symmetric key are not supported in Ms azure sql database v12.

Comment: Because we don't have access to the file system in Azure SQL Database, certificates and keys need to be handled differently. This [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/using-certificates-in-azure-sql-database-import/ba-p/368949) discusses some of the differences.  I think you might need to drop these and re-add them after deployment.

Comment: Thank you. i will go through them and come back if any doubts.